# Protractor fail all tests in test suite

Tags: testing, protractor, suite

Protractor sometimes fail all tests (test suite) if it can't find a element(simple find or protractor.ExpectedConditions) in a single test.

Is it ok?

https://www.screencast.com/t/66NqRQQCBj
https://www.screencast.com/t/Q9tBu4lD

Is there a possible workaround?

Comment: I think, you need to wait until spinner is disappeared. If i'm correct, use EC.invisibilityOf(ele), not EC.presenceOf(ele)

Comment: Spelling, Formatting